# Maximum-LIkelihood Estimation with NLL using parameters in Logscale

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, parameterization

Consider the following toy problem: 
I have  a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ function $f(t,\Theta):[0,t_{\max}] \times (0, \infty)^n \to \mathbb{R}$. I choose some "correct/ground-truth" parameter set $\Theta$, collect some datapoints $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ of $f(\Theta)$ and add Gaussian noise with zero mean and std. deviation $\sigma_i$ to the point $f(t_i, \Theta)$.

Now, I start with some randomly chosen parameters $\Theta '$, and want to minimise the negative log-likelihood w.r.t. the given data. I now heard that fitting in log-scale is the way to go. Since the ground-truth values of $\Theta$ live in a range of $10^{-6},\dots,10^{+8}$. How is this done ? How does the NLL function change here ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your initial points are deterministic numbers and you add "Gaussian noise", your statistical model is an independently but not identically distributed collection of Normal random variables - they are not identically distributed because their variance/std dev differs for each.

Your random variables have the form

$$X_i = f(t_i, \Theta) + V_i, \quad V_i \sim {\rm N}(0, \sigma_i), i=1,...,n$$

and so, using $\phi$ for the standard Normal density, the joint density of the sample $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is

$$h(x_1,\dots, x_n) = \Pi_{i=1}^n\left[\frac 1 {\sigma_i}\phi\left( \frac{x_i -f(t_i, \Theta) }{\sigma_i}\right)\right].$$

Taking natural logs we obtain the log-likelihood of the sample,

$$\mathcal L_n = -\sum_{i=1}^n\ln \sigma_i  -\frac n 2 \ln(2\pi) - \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\left(x_i -f(t_i, \Theta)\right)^2}{2\sigma_i^2}.$$

Assuming that you know the sigmas and you can input them in the above expression (because otherwise your unknown parameters would be more than your data points), go on and maximize as usual the function $\mathcal L_n$ with respect to the elements of $\Theta$.

**If what you want is to apply "log-scale" to the parameters**, then , wherever in $f$ a $\theta_k$ exists, specify in its place in the code $\exp\{\xi_k\}$, and ask the estimator to solve for the $\xi$ parameters.

After obtaining the $\xi$-estimates revert back to the original thetas by exponentiating,
$$\hat \theta_k = \exp\{\hat \xi_k\}$$
and use the Delta method to find the approximate standard errors of the thetas, so here
$${\rm Var}(\hat \theta_k) \approx  \sigma^2_{\xi_k} \cdot \exp\{2\hat \xi\}.$$

Or, since we have

$${\rm Var}(\hat \theta_k) =  {\rm Var}\left(e^{\hat \xi_k}\right) = E\left[ e^{2\hat \xi_k}\right] - \left(E\left [e^{\hat \xi_k}\right]\right)^2,$$

then under asymptotic normality of the estimator, we can use the Moment Generating Function of the Normal distribution so

$${\rm Var}(\hat \theta_k) \approx \exp\{2\hat \xi + 2\sigma^2_{\xi_k}\} - \exp\{2\hat \xi + \sigma^2_{\xi_k}\} = \exp\{2\hat \xi + \sigma^2_{\xi_k}\}\cdot (\exp\{\sigma^2_{\xi_k}\}-1).$$

But these two estimates of the variance deviate quickly as $\sigma_{\xi_k}$ exceeds a few decimal points.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer ! But I don't even need the standard errors explicitly. So I could just stop after exponentiating the found parameters in log-scale ? And whatever parameter transform I use should be completely independent of the NLL function, is that correct ?

Comment: @PaulJoh. Yes, it does not depend on the form of the function.